# filter() method in python django

Tags: python, django, django-views

```
out_links = Link.objects.filter(iweb=iweb_id).order_by('-pub_date')  
for link in out_links:
    comments = LinkComment.objects.filter(link=link.id)
```

Filter method creates the list of object, so out_links is a list, right ?

Next, after for loop, I filtering again to find objects in LinkComments class by link id.

The question arises though, shoud I refer to link as it would be the object or rather a list?
I'm not shure about it as long it is django views? `link.id` or `link['id']`? My python says `[ ]`, but django does not work.

Answer (score 3):

The out_links is a queryset and in the for loop you can reach all LinkComments by:

```
for link in out_links:
    comments = link.linkcomment_set.all()
```

Comment: What if I want to take only link id ?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Can you pls clarify?

Comment: I have a link object taken from this queryset, there is an atribute(id) being kept inside of it. I want to relise ONLY id from this link object. Shoud I do it like this ? `link.id` or `link['id']` in that case

Answer (score 1):

Filter creates a QuerySet, as explained in the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#methods-that-return-new-querysets

If you subscript a QuerySet, like `comments[n]`, you get the nth member (just as you would with a list). Where you have an order_by, that is in the order specified by that clause. You cannot query by id using the subscript notation.

When you iterate over the QuerySet, you get the members of the queryset, which are python model objects, and you may treat them just as you do anywhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

> Filter method creates the list of object, so out_links is a list,
>   right ?

Wrong. It creates [QuerySet object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/), which also happens to be an iterable.